# Unable to copy all data in column to another sheet - excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2013

I am unable to copy all data in a column. I would only want to copy data that does not include the first row, (headers), and paste it to another sheet. My current code gives me a partial result as there are some blanks in between the data.

Please help me out as I am new to VBA. Thanks!

Below are two codes that I have tried. One is through the `xldown` method and the other is the `lastrow`. I found that using the `lastrow`, I am not even able to copy anything at all.

This is the `xldown` method, which gives me partial data (`wsRawT` and `wsDetI` are my defined worksheets):

```
wsRawT.Select
    range("AI1").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).range("A1").Select
    range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.copy

wsDetI.Select
    range("B1").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, -1).range("B1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
```

This is the `lastrow` method, which does not even allow me to copy anything:

```
    Dim lastRowTD As Long
    lastRowTD = wsRawT.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    wsRawT.range("AU2" & lastRowRD).copy
    wsDetI.range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    wsDetS.range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are only small mistakes in your code, try this:

```
Dim lastRowTD As Long
lastRowTD = wsRawT.Cells(Rows.Count, "AU").End(xlUp).Row

wsRawT.Range("AU2:AU" & lastRowTD).Copy
wsDetI.Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

To explain: This code checks how large the dataset in column `A` of your sheet `wsRawT` is. Then it copys everything from cell `A2` down to the last row with data. Then all the values are pasted to column `A` of sheet `wsDetI`. If you don't specifically need the values only, you could also use this simpler version of `.Copy`:

```
wsRawT.Range("AU2:AU" & lastRowTD).Copy wsDetI.Range("A2")
```

Comment: Hi! this seems to work. Am editting this comment because I found a slight error in the data as well. :)

Comment: Adjust this line: `wsRawT.Range("AU2:AU" & lastRowTD).Copy`. I took out the second 2 in `AU2:AU2` since you want that second 2 replaced with `lastRowTD`.

Comment: You may want to qualify `Rows.Count` with the sheet name also, or it will assume you mean the active sheet.

Comment: Also, you should use `AU` in this line: `lastRowTD = wsRawT.Cells(Rows.Count, "AU").End(xlUp).Row`, since this is the column you actually want to copy.

Comment: @braX Doesn't every worksheet have the same number of rows?

Comment: No, they do not.

Comment: How do you permanently delete rows from a worksheet? I didn't know that was possible.

Comment: `lastRowTD = wsRawT.Cells(wsRawT.Rows.Count, "AU").End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: hi @brax  I'm using column A as reference for the lastrow as its the column with complete set of data. the rest of the columns have multiple blanks in between. is this not advisable ?

Comment: @FadhilahAfif you are doing it right, always find the most consistent column to find the last row, with no blank cells.

Comment: @braX In which case would `Rows.Count` return different values in 2 worksheets?

Comment: @M.Schalk suppose you want to count rows from Sheet1 but your activesheet is Sheet2. `Rows.Count` will get them from you activesheet, always. `Sheet1.Rows.Count` will get them from Sheet1 no matter what sheet you are on. If you want to twist it a little more. `MyWorkbook.Sheet1.Rows.Count` will get it from the workbook you want no matter which one is active.

Comment: @Damian But `Rows.Count` will return exactly the same result (1048576) no matter which sheet it is performed on. That's why I'm wondering why you would need to qualify `Rows.Count`. Seems to me like there is no potential for errors here. Am I missing something here?

Comment: That is also true, I think it's the convention... quallify everything no matter if you need to or not.

Comment: I see, makes sense in general I guess. Not much to go wrong if you qualify too much. I was just confused by @braX 's comment that not all worksheets have the same amount of rows. Thanks for chiming in!